# Склонение собственных имен

Tags: морфология, орфоэпия

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли названия компаний в кавычках? Например, подарки от "Компаньона", были предоставлены "Компаньоном" или обязательно надо писать: подарки от МФК "Компаньон", были предоставлены МФК "Компаньон", т.е. микрофинансовой компанией "Компаньон"? При частом употреблении в тексте второй вариант затрудняет чтение..

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта не нарушают норм русского языка. В первом случае склоняется существительное *компаньон* (*подарки от "Компаньона", предоставлены "Компаньоном"*), во втором – существительное *компания* (*подарки от МФК "Компаньон" = от компании "Компаньон", предоставлены МФК "Компаньон" = предоставлены компанией "Компаньон"*). При этом первый вариант действительно читать проще второго, особенно когда читаешь вслух.