# Склонение названий

Tags: склонение, ономастика, морфология

Склоняется ли название организации (к примеру, ООО "Отражение"), если оно употребляется без родового слова "общество" или аббревиатуры ООО? Пример: "В штате "Отражения" более двух тысяч человек" или "В штате "Отражение"...."? Есть ли исключения, в которых название не склоняется? (употребление названия в пресс-релизах, официальных заявлениях, корпоративной газете).

Как должны склоняться названия филиалов и структурных подразделений: "Отражение"-Татарстан, "Инвест-Отражение"? (какая составляющая названия склоняется, а какая - остается неизменной?)

Заранее, благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

См. ответ на схожий вопрос: [тынц.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/998/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD) Если перед собственным наименованием не стоит родового термина, его нужно склонять. Не склоняются лишь наименования, записываемые некириллической графикой: *Руководство Apple запатентовало технологию прикладывания телефона к уху.* "Названия филиалов и структурных подразделений" склоняются как сложные существительные, т.е. изменяется главное слово (в приводимых вами примерах – *Отражение*).